# SET inside UPDATE Statement in MSSQL not working

Tags: sql-server, set, declare

This is the query

```
DECLARE @tempvarA INT = 0
UPDATE Table1 SET @tempvarA = 1 + intColumn, columnA = @tempvarA
```

*intColumn is a column from Table1
It successfully executes the query but the value of columnA is 0 wherein @tempvarA was initially declared. Am I missing something here or does the value of @tempvarA only updates after the execution of the update statement?

I have tried the following:

```
DECLARE @tempvarA INT = 0
UPDATE Table1 SET @tempvarA = 1 + intColumn
UPDATE Table1 SET columnA = @tempvarA
```

It works but somehow I think there should be a more proper way to do it.

Comment: You don't have to issue an `UPDATE` to change the value of a variable. Just simply use `SET @tempvarA = 1`.

Comment: which version of sql server you are using?

Comment: It works nice in sql server 2000.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to say that I need something from the table to compute with @tempvarA. I'll edit it in a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if I understand your question correctly, first you want to declare a variable and set it with a value and then update the value of a column with that variable. Let's take it step by step:

1)Declaring the variable:

```
DECLARE @tempvarA INT;
```

2)Setting the variable:

```
SET @tempvarA = 1;
```

3)Updating table with said variable:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET columnA = @tempvar1;
```

Just be careful though. The above will update ALL the values of `columnA` to that of `tempvarA`. If you want specific rows you will have to add a where clause in your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Hi !, yes your answer is clear! but I can't do step 2) since I need a column in Table1 to be part of my calculations for tempvarA. something like Set tempvarA = 1 + Table1.intColumn. placing the tempvarA = 1 + Table1.intColumn inside the UPDATE statement doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you please accept it as the correct answer as well? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For

```
DECLARE @tempvarA INT = 0
UPDATE Table1 SET @tempvarA = 1, columnA = @tempvarA
```

You can try

```
DECLARE @tempvarA INT = 0
UPDATE t SET @tempvarA = 1, t.columnA = @tempvarA from My_Table_Name t
```

This Works fine for me.

Comment: Hey Thanks! It is working, I've found out that the cause is coming from something else which is my Case statement not properly returning the tempvarA